# I am New in this amazing world of Photography?

Tags: nikon, long-exposure, photography-basics

Disclaimer: I am the first time user of DSLR.

Hi,

I recently bought Nikon D7200 on Christmas. I got 18 mm to 105 mm lens with it. I would like to know what kind of photography I can do using that lens ex: Portrait, Wildlife, Street, Sunrise & Sunset [Long exposure] etc. Biggest confusion for me that distance. Lets say I would like click a close up of eyes of any subject, so how much distance should i maintain for the subject. Also let me know using this lens can I take sunrise and sunset pics which are very much clear. Now regarding mode: I heard most of the professional photographer use Aperture mode.

Guys your response is highly valuable for me, please reply.

Thanks
Atul Agarawal.

Comment: Voting to close because there are several questions here.

Comment: Dear Kamen, At least mentioned some reference, so it would be helpful fo beginners instead of directly voting to close the question, This highly demoralizing someone.

Comment: http://photo.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You'll get much higher quality answers if you post several questions that are specific.

Comment: In this case, I think the best way to proceed is to just try first. If you encounter problems, then ask questions.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Photo.SE. As others have commented, the question you have posted is too broad. This is a Q&A site, where focused questions can get focused answers. You have several, very general and broad questions, most of which have been asked and answered before. Please use the site's search for "D7200", "sunrise" and "sunset", "aperture mode", etc. You will find many questions and answers for all of those subjects. If, after searching, you still have questions, please don't hesitate to ask new focused questions.

Comment: Also, please take a moment and visit the brief [site tour](http://photo.stackexchange.com/tour). Happy shooting!

Comment: Thanks Scott. I'm to photograph as well as photo.se..every one downgrade my question that's really disappointing..

Comment: The pile on of downvotes seems a little unnecessary — I hope it doesn't bring your enthusiasm down. We can definitely help you, but this site isn't a discussion forum or social site. Go out and take pictures, and when you have an individual, specific issue to focus on, we are here to help. (In fact, many questions at once is fine — but break them into separate questions.)

Comment: Thanks mattdm..appreciating..I will do as you suggested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have put many questions into this single post. I recommend you start using the camera, work on one specific problem (such as taking a portrait), and then posting a question relating to some problem you've had there.

However - to give you some broad answers:

> what kind of photography I can do using that lens ex: Portrait, Wildlife, Street, Sunrise & Sunset [Long exposure] etc.

Portrait = yes
Wildlife = some. The biggest obstacle is that you cannot zoom in very much with this lens. The wildlife will be small in your frame. If you walk closer to the wildlife then if it stays there, great, but if it flees or flies away, then you won't be able to get a close shot.
Street = some - think about doing streetscapes (ie. landscape) more than zooming in, for example, on two people having a conversation across the street. 
Sunrise and sunset = yes

In brief, the lens is better suited to landscape (wide open scene, including streetscape) or being close to your subject (nature - flowers, portrait, products, pets, etc) but not strong on zooming in on something that is far away (some wildlife, something high like a sculpture on a building roof)

> Lets say I would like click a close up of eyes of any subject, so how much distance should i maintain for the subject.

You need to play with your lens. Start with photographing people you know. Experiment with your zoom - zoom in from a distance, or walk close and zoom out. There really is no better way for you to learn what you can acheive with eyes than to start taking photos and really experimenting with the entire range of your zoom - but do remember you can walk closer or further away too, to zoom.

> Also let me know using this lens can I take sunrise and sunset pics which are very much clear.

Should be no problem. Clarity depends on 2 things: focusing correctly (and I suggest using your autofocus), and not moving the camera (or subject) while taking the shot. With sunset, the subject doesn't really move. Just hold your hand still while shooting and make sure your shutter speed is above 1/60th of a second for a wide open shot, or above 1/125 if you zoom all the way in.

> I heard most of the professional photographer use Aperture mode.

Ok - here's the big secret. To tell you the truth, this is the wrong question. The biggest tip I will tell you is: first get a vision for what you want to do. When you know what you want to do, *then* we can start asking the questions "what is the best way to acheive this?"

For example, if you say to me "I heard a sedan is a good car" I would say "Well yes, it's a good car if you want to transport 4 people. But if you want to move a load of building material, a ute is better. If you want to compete in a race, a race car is better. If you are moving the contents of your house interstate, a large truck is better". There is no "right" or "best" choice (like aperture mode) - it always depends what you want to do.

How do you work out what you want to do? Start shooting. Seriously. Don't worry about whether the results are bad or whatever - just start shooting. As soon as you do, you can start looking at your results. Spend time thinking about them - what do you like about them? What don't you like? Why? How could you change it next time? It's this last question that's key - you start thinking about how you could improve it, or why one area looks bad and you don't understand what's going on. At this point you start to research for answers on how to improve or change your work, and if you can't find articles, then come back here and ask us some more questions :)

Enjoy it! Learning about photography is lifelong, definitely!

Comment: Thanks a lot for framing the questions again and answering them. Its really helpful for all the beginners who don't know anything about photography. really appreciated, I would like to see your photography work as well, Please share link if you can.

Comment: You're welcome Atul. I've been shooting over 20 years but most of my work is not published :D However here are two links - http://oatley.photography and https://www.facebook.com/chrisrehbergphotography/ 
Photography is an amazing journey in so many ways. It's no wonder it's the world's most popular hobby!

Answer (score -1):

The specs on the Nikon 18-105mm lens says that closest focus is 45 cm.

There is a green dot in lower left corner of viewfinder, which is illuminated green when it finds focus.  If no green dot, then it cannot properly focus (one reason could be too close.  Other reasons could be too dark, or no sharp detail under focus sensor to help find focus).